# Modifying Domain of Many2One using Many2Many

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-enterprise

Just to preface, I'm using Odoo 10 Enterprise.

I have a custom module with the following (these are just the relevant fields) on its form:

- `orange_tag_id` = This is a Many2Many field with the `_Checkboxes` widget defined that's connected to a Tags module (we'll just call it `orange.tags`). This field displays six or seven tags I've created and then applied to various products within the 'product.product/template' module.
- `orange_child_ids` = This is just a One2Many within a child module of the parent module. This lists a `product_tmpl_id` Many2One and then a read-only copy of `orange_tag_id` from the parent that just copies whatever is selected in `orange_tag_id` in the parent form (this was created just in case defining `parent.orange_tag_id` in the domain didn't work).

When a tag is selected from the `orange_tag_id` checkbox, it should sort of modify the domain of `product_tmpl_id` in `orange_child_ids` and then only display the products in the drop-down display that have been tagged with the selected active tag. I've managed to get this sort of working by just adding the following to the form XML view within `orange_child_ids`:

`<field name="product_tmpl_id" domain="[('orange_tag_id.id','in',parent.orange_tag_id[0])]"/>`

This will display only the products that have been tagged with the selected tag with one exception: Tag6's products (just calling it this because its ID was 6) will always display in the drop-down regardless of whether it's selected or not. If Tag2 is selected, then Tag2 and Tag6's products will display. I tried removing Tag6 from any products that had it defined, then deleting the Tag6 record, re-creating the tag, and re-applying it to the relevant products, but the issue persists. I also can only select one tag in the checkbox -- if more than one is selected, I get the following error from `product_tmpl_id`:

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

This isn't as big of a deal as not having the correct records displaying, but I'd also like to resolve this, but I'm not entirely sure how.

I've searched for hours and am aware of methods where this can be done in self-hosted installations, however, we're using Odoo 10 Enterprise (I've omitted the required `x_` in my aforementioned custom fields just for easier readability), and I have no access to the file system and consequently can't make modifications where that's required. I've been trying to figure this out using just the Developer Tools and my administrative access to the database's settings.

I've messed around a lot with the domain, looked through many questions and forum threads, and what I have was the only thing that worked. Is there any way to get this working correctly within the limitations of Enterprise?

Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that adding `[2]` after the `[0]` makes everything work and resolves the two issues I was having, so:

`<field name="product_tmpl_id" domain="[('orange_tag_id.id','in',parent.orange_tag_id[0][2])]"/>`

This will filter the results of the Many2One based on the records selected in the Many2Many field.

Answer (score 0):

While `[('orange_tag_id.id','in',parent.orange_tag_id[0][2])]` will work, it is extremely obscure.

I advise you to go with `[('orange_tag_id.id','in',parent.orange_tag_id.ids)]`

Comment: I had already tried that, and it didn't work. It just listed all records in product.template.